# What is Donic-Schildkröt's "QRC system"?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis

As I know from [official page](https://www.donic-schildkroet.com/en/features/technolgies.html),

> With the QRC (Quick Rubber Change) rubbers you can simply stick on the new or higher-class coverings. The unique Schildkröt QRC system is designed to replace and upgrade rubber and sponge within seconds. Simply pull the old one off and stick on the new one.

But I can't find any video or (more) detailed instruction about how to change one rubber to another. Also I found only three rubbers *supporting QRC* - "QRC-Rubber Liga/Energy/Champ" and that's all.
So, my questions are:

1. Am I need a glue to *install* new rubber?
2. What rubbers I can *install* to the bat with QRC?
3. How exactly to do this?

*P.s.: For context, I'm using Carbotec 900 now.*

Comment: Why not just send the company an email or call them?

Comment: I don't know really, but in most cases official contacts are more complicated and slow then just question on SO. Anyway I've already did it.